# MYSQL Sum of all columns

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
| ID        |  Columnn1  |   Column2     | Column3|
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
|    1      |     3      |     20        |   10   |
|    2      |     4      |     11        |   10   |
|    3      |     5      |     32        |   15   |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
```

Is there any way (aggregate functions) to compute for the sum of all columns (horizontally)? Or how should I do this in query builder for laravel? Or in eloquent?

e.g.

```
row 1 = 3 + 20 + 10 => 33
row 2 => 25
ro2 3 => 52
```

I need to count the sum of all columns not on each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
->selectRaw('*,(Columnn1  +   Column2    + Column3) as sumOfColumns')
```

Comment: perfect! thanks. If I need to get other columns, should I just ->select('other1', 'other2' .......) right?

Comment: Now you don't have to separately mention each column

Comment: I see. Nice. But it gives error "expected type array, found string"

Comment: post your complete query builder to help you further and where you are getting this error?

Comment: I tried to put specific column name instead of *. But * should do it rather. lol. So it is okay now.. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
select id, col1+col2+col3
from tablename
```

Comment: Is there any other way shorter than this one? I have more than 10 columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat("row ", ID, " => " (Columnn1 + Column2 + Column3)) from tablename
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this**

```
SELECT id,(SUM(Columnn1)+SUM(Columnn2)+SUM(Columnn3)) AS total FROM `table_name` GROUP BY id
```

[image: result will be as it]

Comment: this will sum up all rows

Comment: I had uploaded a screenshot of result. you can check it.